# Edit/Create Handlebar with Javascript in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

I looked through the Handlebars documentation which is rather incomplete and found nothing on this. Does anybody know how one would create a Handlebar template with Javascript alone? The only way I know of creating a template currently is with the HTML below. Handlebars.compile will not work in Meteor do to the type of Handlebars used.

```
<template name="foo">
Bar
</template>
```

I want to make a new template, such as 'bar', with Javascript alone (In Meteor). And, after creating said template, how would I obtain the current HTML inside of it and edit it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
Template.foo = function(){return "bar";};
```